# I Need to get a count of activities by month grouped by a Department

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I am trying to get a count of activities by month and group them by a department name.  The report is based on a date parameter that I input to the query "@rptDate".  What I have below works, but I'm guessing there is a better way of doing the same thing and hoping someone can shed some light.

```
Select Count(*) As Month1Count, 0 As Month2Count, 0 As Month3Count,
0 As Month4Count, 0 as Month5Count, 0 as Month6Count, 0 as Month7Count,
0 as Month8Count, 0 as Month9COunt, 0 as Month10Count, 0 as Month11Count,
0 as Month12Count, DepartmentName,ActivityDescription
from reports.WorkOrders
WHERE Month(BeginDate) = Month(@rptDate) and Year(BeginDate) = Year(@rptDate)
Group By DepartmentName, ActivityDescription

UNION

Select 0 As Month1Count, COUNT(*) As Month2Count, 0 as Month3Count,
0 as Month4Count, 0 as Month5Count, 0 as Month6Count, 0 as Month7Count,
0 as Month8Count, 0 as Month9COunt, 0 as Month10Count, 0 as Month11Count,
0 as Month12Count, DepartmentName,ActivityDescription
from reports.WorkOrders
WHERE Month(BeginDate) = Month(@rptDate) + 1  and Year(BeginDate) = Year(DateAdd(month,1,@rptDate))
Group By DepartmentName, ActivityDescription

UNION

Select 0 As Month1Count, 0 As Month2Count, Count(*) as Month3Count,
0 as Month4Count, 0 as Month5Count, 0 as Month6Count, 0 as Month7Count,
0 as Month8Count, 0 as Month9COunt, 0 as Month10Count, 0 as Month11Count,
0 as Month12Count, DepartmentName, ActivityDescription
from reports.WorkOrders
WHERE Month(BeginDate) = Month(@rptDate) + 2  and Year(BeginDate) = Year(DateAdd(month,2,@rptDate))
Group By DepartmentName, ActivityDescription
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The supplied code will give you (up to) three rows of data per department/activity, having respectively the row counts for month 1, 2 and 3 and zeroes for the other months. If that's what you want, I can do that differently. But I'd guess that there is a wrapper for this that adds sums up the months into a single row per Department and Activity (and that there are also a further 9 subqueries to cover the remainder of the year. Do let us know what you need.

Comment: HI Steve, Yes, you are correct, there are a further 9 subqueries to get the remainder of the year and yes,there is a wrapper that sums up the months into a single row per department.  What I'm doing works, but it seems cumbersome and was hoping there might be a more succinct way of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: I've added my answer below, but looking again at the original code, I'm guessing that perhaps @rptDate was always in January? Otherwise the Month + 11 would take you beyond 12 months and cause problems. If my guess is right (and you want to keep things that way), there will be ways to simplify my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested the following, so it's possible there are some typos or minor errors, but I think the following is what you want:

```
SELECT
    sum(case when Month(BeginDate) = Month(dateadd(month,  0, @rptDate)) then 1 else 0 end) as Month1Count,
    sum(case when Month(BeginDate) = Month(dateadd(month,  1, @rptDate)) then 1 else 0 end) as Month2Count,
    sum(case when Month(BeginDate) = Month(dateadd(month,  2, @rptDate)) then 1 else 0 end) as Month3Count,
    sum(case when Month(BeginDate) = Month(dateadd(month,  3, @rptDate)) then 1 else 0 end) as Month4Count,
    sum(case when Month(BeginDate) = Month(dateadd(month,  4, @rptDate)) then 1 else 0 end) as Month5Count,
    sum(case when Month(BeginDate) = Month(dateadd(month,  5, @rptDate)) then 1 else 0 end) as Month6Count,
    sum(case when Month(BeginDate) = Month(dateadd(month,  6, @rptDate)) then 1 else 0 end) as Month7Count,
    sum(case when Month(BeginDate) = Month(dateadd(month,  7, @rptDate)) then 1 else 0 end) as Month8Count,
    sum(case when Month(BeginDate) = Month(dateadd(month,  8, @rptDate)) then 1 else 0 end) as Month9Count,
    sum(case when Month(BeginDate) = Month(dateadd(month,  9, @rptDate)) then 1 else 0 end) as Month10Count,
    sum(case when Month(BeginDate) = Month(dateadd(month, 10, @rptDate)) then 1 else 0 end) as Month11Count,
    sum(case when Month(BeginDate) = Month(dateadd(month, 11, @rptDate)) then 1 else 0 end) as Month12Count
    DepartmentName,
    ActivityDescription
FROM
    reports.WorkOrders
WHERE
    Year(BeginDate) + right('0'+Month(BeginDate),2)
         between Year(@rptDate) + right('0'+Month(@rptDate),2)
             and Year(dateadd(month,11,@rptDate)) + right('0'+Month(dateadd(month,11,@rptDate)),2)
GROUP BY
    DepartmentName,
    ActivityDescription
```

Do let me know how you get on with this. If I've made typos and you can't correct for them, do report the error message and/or any problems with the results.

Comment: Haven't heard back from you @CarlBrydon. Did this work?

Comment: Yes, It Did Steve - Sorry for the delay in responding!